# Rotate an integer to a fixed number of bits

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am  writing a python code which looks at the list and based on the element left shifts the lsb by 1
and based on condition should append 1 0r 0 at LSB.
The maximum count should be 1023 as it should be only 10bit . How can I build that if the number exceeds than 1022 make 3 msbs as zero. I have written a code for it but it is giving false results.

```
readData=file.readline()
LHT=[0]*1024
LPT=[1]*1024
GHR=0

while readData:
    pc,data=readData.split(' ')
    pc=pc[-3:]
    if pc in LHT:
        pc1=pc[-2:]
        pc1=int(pc1)
        if 'T' in data:
            LPT[pc1]=LPT[pc1]+1
            GHR=GHR<<1
            GHR=GHR+1
            if GHR>=1023:
                GHR=GHR-1016
            print("t",GHR)

        if 'N' in data:
            LPT[pc1]=LPT[pc1]-1
            GHR=GHR<<1
            GHR=GHR+0
            if GHR>=1023:
                GHR=GHR-1016
            print("n",GHR)
    else:
        LHT.append(pc)



    readData=file.readline()
```

I am getting this reading which is wrong

```
t 1
n 2
t 5
n 10
t 21
n 42
t 85
n 170
t 341
n 682
t 349
n 698
n 762
t 509
n 1018
t 1021
n 1026
t 1037
n 1058
t 1101
n 1186
t 1357
n 1698
n 2380
n 3744
n 6472
t 11929
n 22842
n 44668
t 88321
n 175626
n 350236
n 699456
```

How can I solve it please help me. Thank you in advance

Expected Output:if my bin(1023)=1111111111 then I want to delete the msbs like 0001111111

Comment: There is no loop in your code, so there is no way you could get that output from that code. Since your code sets `GHR=0`, the output can only be 0 or 1. Please provide the code that actually produces that output.

Comment: Thank you for replying @trincot but I have just uploaded the required part but now I have also pasted the loops please have a look at it

Comment: Well indeed your formula can produce that result. First, why do you say the number can be 1023, but then continue you want to adjust numbers that exceed 1022? That way the number can never be 1023? Which of the two claims is true? Secondly, you say you want to clear the 3 msbs, but 1016 is 0b1111111000, so why do you think subtracting that would clear the 3msbs? Could you provide an example with expected output? That could clear things up...

Comment: I hope this clears the doubt if still not clear I will update it again sorry for the inconvenience @trincot

Comment: What if your number is 1311, do you still want to clear the 3 msbs?

Comment: Yes anything above 1023

Comment: It still is ambiguous in your question whether 1023 is acceptable or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, subtracting 1016 is not going to prevent overflow:

Consider when GHR = 1021, then the next round it will become 2042 (because of the shift). Subtract 1016 from that and you get 1026...

It is not clear why you chose the number 1016. To restrict a number to its 7 least significant bits, you could use either the modulo (`%`) or bitwise AND operator (`&`):

```
if GHR > 1022:
    GHR &= 0b1111111 # only keep 7 least significant bits.
```